# How can I create a one-column dataframe containing all numeric values of a dataframe with several columns?

Tags: r, dataframe, multiple-columns, rows, data-cleaning

Sorry for the basic question here!

I am working the following type of dataset:

`data <- data.frame(a=c(1,2,3), b=c(2,3,4), c=(10,11,12))`

I am trying to turn it into a new data frame where there is only one column, containing all of these values in individual rows, i.e. `a=c(1,2,3,2,3,4,10,11,12)`

What function should I use to arrive at this output?

All the best,

Cameron

Comment: That worked ! If you want to post this as an answer so I can validate it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do `data.frame(a = unlist(data))`.